# cannot get my page to be online using wampserver

Tags: apache, wamp, portforwarding

here are the steps that I did
1- download wampserver and install it
2- go to www/ and write a webpage saying hello
3- I went to localhost and it is running (no problem)
4- I open cmd and type ipconfig to get my ip
5- I used " IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.2" to open the page and it is running (no problem)
6- I went to http://whatismyipaddress.com/ to get my router ip
7- I tried it and it is not working
8- I open the router setting page 
9- I enable forwarding of port 80 to 10.0.0.2
10- I went to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to see if port 80 is open using the router ip
11- I find it open
12- I disconnected my wamp from my computer
13- port 80 is closed when I close wamp
14- I reconnect wamp but I could not get to my webpage.
Can anybody tell me what is the problem

Comment: If localhost is running you should see the webpage. Confirm your web page path(url) and page content.

Comment: I am doing a distributed application. I most run it in many nodes. I need to open it from outside

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not wanting to be a smart*ss but maybe following links helps you without reinventing the wheel again.
 [Make WAMP www available on local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657279/make-wamp-www-available-on-local-network)
[Cannot access wamp server on local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219062/cannot-access-wamp-server-on-local-network)
[access wamp from lan without puting online](https://superuser.com/questions/131885/how-can-i-access-wamp-from-lan-without-puting-online)

Hoping that these will help you a little, if not, please let us know here.
*If one of the links helped please mark the question as solved here.*

Comment: I can access wamp server on local network. I want to access wamp server from the internet

Comment: It seems that (your own list) point 6/7 is the problem. Without that ip number there is not much to connect to from the internet.  
If http://whatismyipaddress.com/ is not working then maybe 
http://showip.net/ or http://findwhatismyipaddress.org/ will do the job.  
If not..then you have another issue and probably the cause of all.
You mentioned (point 8/9) you did some config, imho there is *somewhere* in the router the option to read out it actual ip.  
If not and you have no clue how to find out yourself then your ISP knows howto.

Comment: Great to hear, but how do you connect from the internet to your local website when you dont have a domain/ip? Anyway, if all works, you mark the question as solved please.