# Set up WAMP server - getting 403

Tags: apache, wamp, apache-config

I want to put my website online. I am using WampServer 2.2. Now, I've set up wamp as follows:

```
<Directory />
  AllowOverride All
  Options All
  Require all granted
  Order allow,deny
</Directory>

Listen 81
<VirtualHost *:81>
  ServerName rti.etf.rs
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

I've opened up port 81 in Windows Firewall. Now, when I try opening localhost:81 my webpage opens well. However, when I try accessing it with my external IP address 176.xxx.xxx.xxx:81, I get a 403 Forbidden error. I see these requests in the Apache access log, so I guess that part is set up well, but I must be missing something it the Apache configuration.

Edit: Put Online option is activated.

Any helpful ideas?

Comment: Put Online menu option? http://imgur.com/xGago or have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657279/make-wamp-www-available-on-local-network

Comment: Oh, I forgot to write that I also did Put Online my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK try this, you didn't specify which version of Apache you were using and you seem to have Apache 2.2 syntax mixed up with Apache 2.4 syntax so I have given both versions.

Change this section back to how it was originally, this controls access to your `C:\` and you just allowed full access to it, NOT GOOD.

From

```
<Directory />
  AllowOverride All
  Options All
  Require all granted
  Order allow,deny
</Directory>
```

to 
Apache 2.2.x syntax

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Apache2.4.x syntax

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Now to your Virtual Hosts. This also need to have it's own security specified inside the  block

```
Listen 81
<VirtualHost *:81>
  ServerName rti.etf.rs
  DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
#### Apache 2.2 syntax
  <Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
     AllowOverride All
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from all
  </Directory>
#### Apache 2.4 syntax
  <Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

PS.
I cannot see any benefit in using port 81 and it just makes life more complicated for an external user.